# files that cannot be transfered from dvd to removable drive

Tags: file-transfer, crc

what is the solution if there is always an error while transferring a file->data error:crc
I tried to play the video file which cannot be transferred and it can be played from the dvd but when I try to transfer it using terra copy. I always see this crc error.